# How can I get the cell near the one modified?

Tags: google-apps-script

I use onEdit to run a function but I can get how to address the cell on the right to the one edited ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried the [offset method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_range?hl=fr-FR#offset) ?

> method offset(rowOffset, columnOffset, optNumRows, optNumColumns)
>
> Gets a new range relative to a given range.

For example:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().offset(0, 1)
```